# Open cart 1.5.6 select description rule

Tags: php, opencart

I am trying to do one change in opencart source code (1.5.6 version), but unfortunately without success.

We have 5 languages on website with descriptions.

I want to show english description for the products on all version of languages on web site (on the page: ?route=product/product&product_id=X)

All other content will be on selected language but only description need be on english (no matter what language is selected).

I am searching for solution, and only logical for me is that this changes in code need to be make on product.php file under catalog/controller/product dir.

But can anybody give to me advice where to change the line of code where open cart select language id? In database english is language_id = 1

Maybe I can do this

remove this line on product.tpl

```
<div id="tab-description" class="tab-content"><?php echo $description; ?></div>
```

and put something like this, but how select description in this case

```
<div id="tab-description" class="tab-content"><?php SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM DATABASE WHERE LANGUAGE_ID =1 ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mainly you need to modify your Model, Controller and View files:

Open you product model file from here : `catalog/model/catalog/product.php`

Add following code before **line no 64** or `public function getProducts($data = array()) {`

```
public function getProductEngDesc($product_id) {
      $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) WHERE p.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND pd.language_id = '1' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'");

      if ($query->num_rows) {
            return array(
                'description' => $query->row['description'],
            );
        } else {
            return false;
        }
  }
```

Open you product Controller file from here : `catalog/controller/product/product.php`

Add following line after `$product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);`

```
$product_eng_desc = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductEngDesc($product_id);
```

Add following line after `$this->data['description'] = html_entity_decode($product_info['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');`

```
$this->data['eng_description'] = html_entity_decode($product_eng_desc['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Now open your `Product` template file and replace below line

```
<div id="tab-description" class="tab-content"><?php echo $description; ?></div>
```

With

```
<div id="tab-description" class="tab-content"><?php echo $eng_description; ?></div>
```

Comment: Nice solution. Thank You very much, I'll study for examples in future. BR